# Scroll two different scrollviewers at the same time

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, scrollviewer

I have two scrollviewers in my application and when the first one of them is being scrolled vertically, I want the second scrollview to scroll horizontally (simultaneously).

Are there any methods that can help me do this, and how can I determine a specific position for the second scrollviewer while the first one is scrolled?

Comment: You should be able to bind the `Value` of the horizontal scrollbar to the `Value` of the vertical one.

Comment: Yes I know but at what point should I do that? I want the scrolling to happen simultaneously for both elements and I'm guessing that there's some method I can overwrite while the scrolling is happening on the first element.

Comment: Use `Value="{Binding Value, ElementName=VerticalScrollBar, Mode=TwoWay}"`, though it does mean that when you scroll the horizontal one the vertical one moves as well. Not sure if this is the behaviour you want though.